# How to find the closed form of $\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\ln \left(x^n+1\right)}{x^n+1}\:\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Is there a closed form for $$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\ln \left(x^n+1\right)}{x^n+1}\:\mathrm{d}x$$
I tried multiple techniques such as the elementary ones but none really work out which leads me to think that it can maybe be expressed in special functions.
¿Can you please help me find if this has a closed form or not?.

Comment: See this https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h340081p1820224

Comment: @Souza differetiation under the integral sign doesnt seem to help much here.

Comment: Note that for $n=1$ the integral does not converge.

Comment: Did you see the last post on this link ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the following identity,
$$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{1}{\left(x^n+1\right)^m}\:dx=\frac{1}{n}\:\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\Gamma \left(m-\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\Gamma \left(m\right)}$$
If we differentiate both sides with respect to $m$ we get,
$$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\ln \left(x^n+1\right)}{\left(x^n+1\right)^m}\:dx=\frac{1}{n}\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\Gamma \left(m-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(\psi \left(m\right)-\psi \left(m-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)}{\Gamma \left(m\right)}$$
Now setting $m=1$ will get us the result of your integral,
$$\boxed{\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\ln \left(x^n+1\right)}{x^n+1}\:dx=-\frac{1}{n}\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\Gamma \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(\gamma +\psi \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)}$$
Where $\gamma$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) and $\psi $ the [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Some interesting values can be obtained with this,
$$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\ln \left(x^2+1\right)}{x^2+1}\:dx=-\frac{1}{2}\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\gamma +\psi \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)=-\frac{\pi }{2}\left(\gamma -\gamma -2\ln \left(2\right)\right)$$
$$=\pi \ln \left(2\right)$$

Comment: To prove the initial identity use the sub $\displaystyle u=\frac{1}{\left(x^n+1\right)^m}$ and use one of the integral definitions of the Beta function.

Comment: The general form can be simplified using the reflection formula for the Gamma function.

Answer (score 3):

Denote $$I(n)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln(1+x^n)}{1+x^n}dx,\; \; \forall  n>1$$ setting $1+x^n\to x$ and $x\to \frac{1}{x}=t$ we yield $$\begin{aligned}I(n)&= \frac{1}{n}\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x}\frac{\sqrt[n]{x-1}}{x(x-1)}dx\\& =-\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1{t^{-1/n}(1-t)^{1/n-1}}\ln tdt\\&=-\frac{1}{n}\frac{\partial}{\partial k}\int_0^1t^{k}(1-t)^{m}dt\end{aligned}$$ where $k=-\frac{1}{n}$ and $m=\frac{1}{n}-1$ and the last expression we have is nothing but the [derivatives of *beta function*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20beta%20function,0%2C%20Re%20y%20%3E%200.) and hence $$\begin{aligned} I(n)& =-\frac{1}{n}\frac{\partial}{\partial k}\beta\left(1+k,m+1\right)\\&=-\frac{1}{n}\beta(1+k,m+1)\left(\psi^0\left(1+k\right)+\gamma\right)\\&=-\frac{1}{n}\underbrace{\Gamma\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}_{\text{reflection formula}}\left(\psi^0(k+1)+\gamma\right)=-\frac{\pi}{n\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})}\left(\psi^0\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)+\gamma\right)\\&=-\frac{\pi}{n\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})}H_{-\frac{1}{n}}\end{aligned}$$

For $n=60$  it is interesting to derive the following closed form

> $$\begin{aligned}I(60)=&  \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x^{60})}{1+x^{60}}dx\\& =-\frac{\pi}{15}\frac{H_{-\frac{1}{60}}}{\sqrt{8-\sqrt{12-4\phi}-2\sqrt{3}\phi}}\end{aligned}$$
> **Notation:** $\phi$ is *Golden ratio*.