# Prove $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln^2(x^3+1)}{x^3+1} dx = \frac{\sqrt{3} \pi}{18} \left(9\ln^2(3)+4\psi ^{\prime} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\right)-\ldots$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Prove $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln^2{(x^3+1)}}{x^3+1} \; \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\sqrt{3} \pi}{18} \left(9\ln^2{(3)}+4\psi ^{\prime} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\right)-\frac{\pi^3 \sqrt{3}}{54}-\frac{\pi}{3}\ln{(3)}$$
I tried feynman method with $ I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln^2\left(ax^3+1\right)}{x^3+1} \; \mathrm{d}x$ but this got ugly because we need to differentiate wrt a twice I think.  I also try to factor $x^3+1$ and either partial fraction decomposition denominator or log property for numerator but these did not work.  I am not sure what to do now. Im not very good with contour integration so can people who respond try to use real methods?? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How find this integral $I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\ln{(1+\tan^4{x})})^2\frac{2\cos^2{x}}{2-(\sin{(2x)})^2}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873333/how-find-this-integral-i-int-0-frac-pi2-ln1-tan4x2-frac2)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the closed form of $\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\ln \left(x^n+1\right)}{x^n+1}\:\mathrm{d}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3748162/how-to-find-the-closed-form-of-int-0-infty-frac-ln-leftxn1-rightx)

Comment: There's a misprint in your proposed answer:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi}{18} \left(9\ln^2{(3)}+4\psi ^{\prime} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\right)-\frac{\pi^3 \sqrt{3}}{54}-\frac{\pi^{\color{red}{\large 2}}}{3}\ln{(3)}
$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the parameterized integral $I(a)$ where the integral in question is equal to $I''(1)$:

$$I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(x^3+1\right)^a} \; \mathrm{d}x$$
First, let $x^3 \to x$:
\begin{align}
I(a) &= \frac{1}{3} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{-\frac{2}{3}}}{(t+1)^a} \notag \\
 & \; \; = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\Gamma\left(a-\frac{1}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(a\right)} \notag 
\end{align}
Where we used the definition of the beta function.

Now we will find $I''(1)$:
\begin{align}
I'(a) &= \frac{d}{da} \left( \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\Gamma\left(a-\frac{1}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(a\right)} \right) \notag \\
 &= \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\Gamma\left(a-\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(\psi\left(a-\frac{1}{3}\right)-\psi\left(a\right)\right)}{\Gamma\left(a\right)} \notag \\
I''(a) &= \frac{d}{da} \left( \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\Gamma\left(a-\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(\psi\left(a-\frac{1}{3}\right)-\psi\left(a\right)\right)}{\Gamma\left(a\right)} \right) \notag \\ 
&= \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\Gamma\left(a-\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(\psi\left(a-\frac{1}{3}\right)^2-2\psi\left(a\right)\psi\left(a-\frac{1}{3}\right)+\psi\left(a\right)^2+\psi^{\prime}\left(a-\frac{1}{3}\right)-\psi^{\prime}\left(a\right)\right)}{\Gamma\left(a\right)} \notag \\
I''(1) &= \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\left(\psi\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2-2\psi\left(1\right)\psi\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)+\psi\left(1\right)^2+\psi^{\prime}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-\psi^{\prime}\left(1\right)\right)}{\Gamma\left(1\right)} \notag \\
 &= \frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}\left(-\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac{9\ln^2{(3)}}{4}-\frac{\pi \sqrt{3} }{2} \ln{(3)} + \psi^{\prime} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\right) \notag \\
 &= \boxed{\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi}{18} \left(9\ln^2{(3)}+4\psi ^{\prime} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\right)-\frac{\pi^3 \sqrt{3}}{54}-\color{red}{\frac{\pi^2}{3}\ln{(3)}}} \notag
\end{align}
It appears that the result of the integral you provided is slightly off (see the red term).  [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20ln%5E2%281%2Bx%5E3%29%2F%281%2Bx%5E3%29%20dx%20from%200%20to%20infty) agrees with the [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%283%29*pi%2F18%289ln%5E2%283%29%2B4*polygamma%281%2C2%2F3%29%29-pi%5E3*sqrt%283%29%2F54-pi%5E2%2F3*ln%283%29) I provided as well.

Comment: Maybe answer key had a typo.  Thanks

Comment: The same 5 down votes hours after a perfectly correct accepted answer.  Someone has some sort of a vendetta and just uses 5 accounts to downvote my answers or what?  This is at least the third time this has happened within a couple of days.  I assume its the same 5 people who upvoted Dennis Orton's comment since it all happened at around the same time.

Comment: This looks like a serious issue. Perhaps you should flag this answer and tell moderators what happened?

Comment: @pisco. I flagged the answer.  Thanks for the idea.  It is just strange how this started recently and occurs on some but not all of my answers.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln^{2}\pars{x^{3} + 1} \over x^{3} + 1}\,\dd x}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\large x^{3}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln^{2}\pars{x + 1} \over x + 1}\,
{1 \over 3}\,x^{-2/3}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.{1 \over 3}\,\partiald[2]{}{\nu}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\color{red}{1/3} - 1}\,\pars{x + 1}^{\nu - 1}\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ \nu\ =\ 0}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\mbox{However,}\quad
\pars{x + 1}^{\nu - 1} & = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
{\nu - 1 \choose k}x^{k} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{{k - \nu \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}}x^{k}
\\[5mm] &=
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
\color{red}{\Gamma\pars{k - \nu + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{1 - \nu}}\,
{\pars{-x}^{k} \over k!}
\end{align}
With the [Ramanujan Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem), (\ref{1}) becomes:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln^{2}\pars{x^{3} + 1} \over x^{3} + 1}\,\dd x} =
\left.{1 \over 3}\,\partiald[2]{}{\nu}
\bracks{\Gamma\pars{1 \over 3}{\Gamma\pars{-1/3 - \nu + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{1 - \nu}}}
\,\right\vert_{\ \nu\ =\ 0}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{{2 \over 9}\,\root{3}\pi\,\Psi\, '\pars{2 \over 3} +
{1 \over 2}\,\root{3}\pi\ln^{2}\pars{3} -
{1 \over 3}\pi^{2}\ln\pars{3} - {1 \over 54}\,\root{3}\pi^{3}}
\\[5mm] \approx &\ 2.3798
\end{align}